# Function to test Windows activation

Tags: powershell, scripting

New to #powershell and especially I'm trying to learn how functions work. I am building a Windows form that an end-user at a remote location can use to install a piece of software and setup a few things in the OS environment.

I have a point in my form where I need to perform Windows activation, then check whether it has succeeded or not. I'm using a simple if/else statement, but I would like to wrap it into a function that I can just keep calling once the user clicks on a button.

Here's what I currently have. This code works for me, I just can't figure out how to make it into a function. and most of the examples I find online are either too basic "hello world" type functions or very complex beyond my noob ability to comprehend at this time. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$Win_Act = cscript c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /ato) {
$status = $Win_Act
if ($status -eq $False) {write-host "Windows is not activated"}
Else {write-host "Windows Activated Successfully"}
```

1. User clicks on button
2. Function is called
3. If it succeeds, message box pops up saying "Successful" (Script continues)
4. If it fails, message box pops up saying "Failed, check connection"
5. User clicks on button which runs function again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you aren't inputting anything, you don't require any parameters. So you could just create a function to do what you already have an then return the string. Something like this:

```
function Function_Name(){
    if (4 -eq 4){
        Return "A message"
    }else{
        Return "Another message"
    }
}
```

Then to get the output and put it into a variable to update your form, you could do:

```
$variableName = Function_Name
```

I hope this helps a little, I would warn against putting hard-coded values/paths in your scripts. You could have these as variables at the top of your script which get "injection" into the function using a parameter. Just a thought :)

Comment: Thanks for that. Still drinking from the firehose sadly, so I'm not really sure how Parameters work yet. Been a little over a month since I started with Powershell. I'll give this a go.

Comment: @Spartan If you're having difficulty understanding functions and parameters, I would take a step back and learn PowerShell before building and deploying production scripts :)

Comment: You have a point. I won't deploy anything before I understand it, hence asking questions on here, reading, and trial and error are what I'm doing to improve :)

Comment: @Spartan Sounds like a plan, we look forward to your future questions <3

Answer (score 2):

if you want to avoid running the vbscript - slmgr.vbs - you could do something like this

```
function test-activation {

    $ta = Get-CimInstance -ClassName SoftwareLicensingProduct -Filter "PartialProductKey IS NOT NULL" |
    Where-Object -Property Name -Like "Windows*" 

    if ($ta.LicenseStatus -eq 1) {$true} else {$false}
 }
```

Comment: Ooh that's nice. Didn't know there was another way without using vbscript. I'll give this a shot. Much appreciated.